# Download file from link and check if download is complete nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I try to download a file from a link

This my code

```
  const url ="https://lalalai.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/media/split/a703a60c-54f3-48f4-91b5-43a60c-54f3-48f4-91b5-4b3bc71dfd2f/accompaniment";
  const file = fs.createWriteStream("./uploads/exp.mp3");
  https.get(url, async function (response) {
    await response.pipe(file);
    console.log("done");
  });
```

The problem is, the server return "done" but the downloaded file still not finished.
Can someone help me? thanks:D

Answer (score 1):

I think you can listen to event and apply callback for what will happen for that particular event. below is the example code.

```
const url ="https://lalalai.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/media/split/a703a60c-54f3-48f4-91b5-43a60c-54f3-48f4-91b5-4b3bc71dfd2f/accompaniment";
  const file = fs.createWriteStream("./uploads/exp.mp3");
  https.get(url, async function (response) {
    response.pipe(file);
    console.log("downloading started");

    response.on("error", (err) => {
      console.log("some error occurred while downloading");
      throw err;
    });
  
    response.on("end", () => {
      console.log("it worked, download completed");
    });
    
 });
```

Sometimes file being downloaded comes in response.body instead of response so check for that also if above doesn't work.